# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. app crushed

Tags: javascript, server, header

I'm getting this error -> " Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client ".I tried to apply JSON Web Token(JWT) in my app and every time it's logging me out from app. I can't understand is it server-side error or client-side. Pls check my code

Here is the code:

```
    // verifyJWT function
        function verifyJWT(req, res, next){
            const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
            if (!authHeader) {
                return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Your access is unauthorized to BookPile' });
            }
        
        
            const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
            jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRECT, (err, decoded) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(403).send({ message: 'BookPile authority forbid your access' })
                }
                console.log('decoded', decoded);
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            })
        
        
            console.log('inside verify function', authHeader);
            next();
        }
```

//API

```
// GET API for get token
        app.post('/login' , async(req,res) => {
            const user = req.body;
            const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
                expiresIn:'1d'
            });
            res.send({accessToken});
        }) 



// GET API for load items of logged in user
        app.get('/my_items' , verifyJWT ,  async(req,res) => {
            // const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
            // console.log(authHeader);
            const email = req.query.email;
            const criteria = {email:email};
            const cursor = await booksCollection.find(criteria);
            const books = await cursor.toArray();
            res.send(books);
        })
```

```
//Client side
const getMyBooks = async () => {
            const email = user.email;
            const url = `http://localhost:5000/my_items?email=${email}`;
           
            try {
                const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
                    headers: {
                        authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
                    }
                })

                setMyBooks(data);
            }

            catch (error) {
                console.log((error.message));
                if (error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 403) {
                    signOut(auth);
                    // navigate('/login');
                }
            }

           
        }
        getMyBooks();
    }, [user])
```

```
//Client side login
const handleForm = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const email = emailRef.current.value;
        const password = passRef.current.value;

        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', { email });
        // console.log(data);
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.accessToken);
        navigate(from, { replace: true });
    }
```

Comment: "I can't understand is it server-side error or client-side", it's server-side

Answer (score 0):

Since the verify function is executed asynchronously, the last `next()` call will be called immediately before the verification is done. Therefore you'll have to call either `res.send()` or `next()` inside the callback

```js
function verifyJWT(req, res, next){
            const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
            if (!authHeader) {
                return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Your access is unauthorized to BookPile' });
            }
        
        
            const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
            jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRECT, (err, decoded) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(403).send({ message: 'BookPile authority forbid your access' })
                }
                console.log('decoded', decoded);
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            })
        }
```